# Sort data set by biggest range of entries

Tags: r, sorting

I am dabbling my feet in **R** a bit and I am now able to sort columns by their means but I would now like to sort the columns by the biggest range of the data points in each column.

Say I have a table with a point rating for movies. How can I get the Top 10 movies where the opinions are most different. Is there a function that can measure this? One idea of mine was to use perhaps the minValue ans maxValue but then just one outlier can mess it all up.

I guess the size of the box of a boxplot could be a pretty good measure.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

So I tried sorting my table by their respective `sd()` but I cant quite get that to work. What I was trying is this. The table has headings btw. and is named `newdata` here.

```
> newdata.sd <- sapply(1:107, function(j) sd(newdata[,j], na.rm=TRUE))
> newdata.sorted.sd <- newdata[,names(sort(newdata.sd, decreasing=TRUE))]
```

The second line throws an error because the first doesn't produce a `Named num` vector.
When I did the same thing with sorting by the columns means it worked. That I did with the following two lines.

```
> newdata.mean <- colMeans(newdata, na.rm=TRUE)
> newdata.sorted <- newdata[,names(sort(newdata.mean, decreasing=TRUE))]
```

How can I produce a named vector of `sd()`s like in the second example?
A different way to sort by `sd()` would be also appreciated.

Comment: Are you really just looking for a statistic that measures variability? There's a fairly standard one: the standard deviation (`sd()`). Or you could use the interquartile range (`IQR()`--which is the size of a box in a boxplot, by the way).

Comment: Both functions look very good. Thanks. What do you think measures better what I want?

Comment: Standard deviation is considered a more robust description of variability, as it takes into account each value; however, it is more affected by outliers than interquartile range.  Pick your poison.

Comment: got it. `> newdata.sd <- sapply(newdata, sd, na.rm=TRUE)` does the trick.